# How to "remove"/"change" some require(...) calls when using browserify?

Tags: javascript, node.js, browserify

I have app written in node.js that requires some npm modules (react, react-router and others). When I run browserify on it, then all npm modules are "injected" to the bundle.js file. What I want is to provide distribution for bower that won't include react and react-router dependencies in bundle.js file, because they can be referenced as dependencies in bower.json.

app.js:

```
var React = require('react')
React.render(...)
```

In bundle.js react is injected into it along with app.js

I need bundle.js that will not contain react and will assume that it is available in global (window) scope.

bundle.js:

```
React.render(...)
```

or something like this:

```
var require = function(name){ return window[name] }
var React = require('react')
React.render(...)
```

So basically I want to tell browserify that SOME of the modules can be found in `window` scope and don't have to be injected in to the bundle.js...

Comment: Not sure if there is a way to do it with Browserify configs directly, but the package [browserify-shim](https://www.npmjs.com/package/browserify-shim) seems to handle your use case.

Comment: Hey I couldn't manage to make it work with browserify-shim, however I found this module browserify-global-shim which just replaces specified module requires (`require('XXX')` => `window.XXX`)

Comment: @user606521 Thanks to you my problem got solved here buddy! Thanks!
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34681058/how-to-browserify-a-file-that-includes-a-node-module-with-an-equivalent-client-v

Answer (score 1):

Use `-x [Module Name]` to exclude node modules from the bundle.

```
browserify -d -x react -x react-router app.js > bundle.js
```

Comment: Do you know how I can use -x option from the code (not cli)? I can't find corresponding browserify option in documentation...

Comment: Sry, i do not know, how to use it from the code. But why do you need to make these modules global? You could bundle them into a separate file.

Comment: You can check if the module exists. `var React = require('react');`. `React` will be undefined, if it cannot find the module.

Comment: I want to make my package bower-available. In bower you just type dependencies in bower.json instead of bundling them along with your own library code.