# How to browserify a file that includes a node module with an equivalent client version?

Tags: javascript, node.js, browserify

Found a [package](https://github.com/thlorenz/browserify-swap) that does replace, going to test with that.
Now if `file.node` gets replaced with `file.min.js` my question would be, how to not browserify this dependency i.e.  not browserify `file.min.js` again ?

I've a package that has a browserified and minified 
`file.min.js`
and its node version

> file.node

it is used (as in `modName = require("file.node")` ) by many files.

but `file.node` cannot be browserified. don't ask why.

Many files depend upon modName module.

The `file.min.js` also contains modName such that

`<script src='file,min.js' >` exposes modName (umd for those who know);

Is there a way to browserify my pacakges main file `main.js` (which contains files that depend upon modName) such that I can replace the module `file.node` with `file.min.js` ;

Found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32850263/2290820) somewhat helpful

Comment: see answer below to get clarity

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to this guy's [solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30965909/how-to-remove-change-some-require-calls-when-using-browserify#comment49971279_30965909)

which might be a problem to others looking for an answer, this got solved.

Just doing

`globalShim = require('browserify-global-shim').configure({
                    nodeModuleName: clientModuleName
                }),`

replaces,

`nodeModule = require('nodeModuleName')`

with 

`clientModuleName`

in browser which is `window.clientModuleName` actually.